# C# 2X8 ARRAY Placing Similar Items

Tags: arrays

I have 5 items:
A,B,C,D,E

I need to assign them to 2x8 array, but I need to place similar items far as possible and if possible simetric place

For example if the amount of each items contain following

A= 2, B= 2, C=3, D=4, E=5

Manually I can do the following

E   C   D   A   B   C   E   D

D   E   C   B   A   D   E   E

I tried too many thing with random, but the program hangs in loop

Could you give me any idea

Thanks

Comment: The specification isn't clear. Also, if you need help with a program that is in a loop, you'll need to post some relevant code.

Comment: Hi Darius, I have explained the specification in the program

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();


        richTextBox3.Text = "";

        // I have 5 kind of material, each of them have the following amount:
        // type A=2
        // type B=2
        // type C=3
        // type D=4
        // type E=5
        int[] materials = { 2, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        int Xa = materials[0];  // material A amount
        int Xb = materials[1];  // material B amount
        int Xc = materials[2];
        int Xd = materials[3];
        int Xe = materials[4];

        //  I need to place them in 2 row * 8 column
        // when doing this assignment I should place the similar materials far away as possible
        // It possible symetric order

        string[,] array = new string[2,8];
        Array.Clear(array, 0, array.Length);

        array[0, 0] = "E"; // As beginnig I assigned to (0,0) the most biggest material(E)
        Xe = Xe - 1;

        array[1, 0] = "D";// For the second row (1,0) the second biggest material (D)
        Xd = Xd - 1;


        // first row

        for (int j = 1; j < 8; j++) // I used the first column for D and E material
            {
                int random = rnd.Next(0, 5); // I randomly choose one of the material

                // if the column is blank (not assigned before and
                // If the random material is 0 (A type) and the amount of A is not 0
                // and the previous column is not assigned with A type
                if (array[0,j]=="" && random == 0 && Xa != 0 && array[0,j-1]!="A")
                {

                        array[0,j] = "A"; // assign A to this column
                        Xa = Xa - 1; // reduce A amount


                        richTextBox3.Text += "A"; // write "A" in text box
                        richTextBox3.Text += " ";


                }

                // B type condition
                else if (array[0,j]=="" && random == 1 && Xb != 0 && array[0,j-1]!="B")
                {

                        array[0,j] = "B"; // assign B to this column
                        Xb = Xb - 1; // reduce B amount


                        richTextBox3.Text += "B"; // write "B" in text box
                        richTextBox3.Text += " "; 

                }
                // C type condition
                else if (array[0, j] == "" && random == 2 && Xc != 0 && array[0, j - 1] != "C")
                {

                    array[0, j] = "C"; // assign C to this column
                    Xc = Xc - 1; // reduce C amount


                    richTextBox3.Text += "C"; // write "C" in text box
                    richTextBox3.Text += " ";

                }

                     // D type condition
                else if (array[0, j] == "" && random == 3 && Xd != 0 && array[0, j - 1] != "D")
                {

                    array[0, j] = "D"; // assign D to this column
                    Xd = Xd - 1; // reduce D amount


                    richTextBox3.Text += "D"; // write "D" in text box
                    richTextBox3.Text += " ";

                }
                // E type condition
                else if (array[0, j] == "" && random == 4 && Xd != 0 && array[0, j - 1] != "E")
                {

                    array[0, j] = "E"; // assign E to this column
                    Xe = Xe - 1; // reduce E amount


                    richTextBox3.Text += "E"; // write "C" in text box
                    richTextBox3.Text += " ";

                }




                else j = j - 1; // if all above not true try again
            }
        }
```